# How to select all print statement in VScode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm writing python script using VS code. I'm using lots of prints statement while developing. Now I'm having trouble to clear all print statement in VS code editor.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select one `print` statement and afterwards press CTRL+F2 (change all occurrence)

I hope [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) will help you